# Return the exact portion string passing the same portion that is all lower case

Tags: javascript

We have a string with a normal first letter as a capital letter in `reference`.

What if we want to return the exact portion of `reference` passing the same portion that is all lower case!

So if we want to return the `I would study Math in the UK.` from `reference` variable then we only need to pass the lowercase version like this:

```
getReferencePortion('i would study math in the uk.');
```

```js
let reference = 'If I were you, I would study Math in the UK.';
getReferencePortion('i would study math in the uk.');
function getReferencePortion(portion){   
     // if there is a match then return: I would study Math in the UK.
}
```

Comment: did you purposely remove the `the` in your input to your function call? What do you want returned if there is no match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could lowercase the reference string and then use `indexOf` to see if the substring is contained. If so you can then use `substr` to pull out the subset of the original string.

```js
function getReferencePortion(reference, portion) {
  let index = reference.toLowerCase().indexOf(portion);

  if (index !== -1) {
    return reference.substr(index, portion.length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a with a regular expression ignoring case (the `i` flag) with [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and a default. To build the regular expression from your input you can use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_regular_expression) constructor, which will match any string that equals your input string by ignoring caps:

```js
const reference = 'If I were you, I would study Math in the UK.';

function getReferencePortion(portion){   
  return (reference.match(new RegExp(portion, 'i')) || ["No match"]).pop();;
}

console.log(getReferencePortion('i would study math in the uk.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the RegExp Named group with ignore case.

```js
const reference = "If I were you, I would study Math in the UK.";

function getReferencePortion(portion) {
  const match = reference.match(new RegExp(`(?<ref>${portion})`, "i"));
  return match ? match.groups.ref : "No Match";
}

console.log(getReferencePortion("i would study math in the uk."));
```